# error using the map function from purr package

Tags: r, dictionary, tidyverse

I want to use the map function but I have trouble fixing an error.

```
> values <- T8_mut %>% select (start)
> values
    start
1  610661
2 1366584
3 1570287
4 1948432
5 2047458
> get_pos1 <- function(x) {
+     T8 %>% 
+     mutate(abs_diff = abs(start - x)) %>% arrange(abs_diff) %>% slice_head(n = 1) 
+ }
> nucdiff_genes <- as.data.frame(map(values, get_pos1 ))
Warning message:
Problem while computing `abs_diff = abs(start - x)`.
ℹ longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length 



> T8 %>% mutate(abs_diff = abs(start - 610661)) %>% arrange(abs_diff) %>% slice_head(n = 1) 
  seqnames  start    end width strand   source type score phase         ID                           Name  locus_tag                        product       Dbxref
1 contig_1 610793 611278   486      + Prodigal  CDS    NA     0 C347_02750 IS200/IS605 family transposase C347_02750 IS200/IS605 family transposase COG:COG1....
             gene inference anti_codon amino_acid pseudo            func abs_diff
1 tnp-IS200,iS605      <NA>       <NA>       <NA>   <NA> tnp-IS200,iS605      132
>
```

the code works when I fill it in manually however, when using the map function, I get the error shown above.

Comment: Inside the function you call `T8 %>% ...` and outside it is called `T8_mut`. That seems to be your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that when you're calling `map` on `values` what you're actually telling it to iterate over is a dataframe of 1 column. R takes that to mean "for each column do this function". To map over the values contained in the column itself, `pull` it from the dataframe to create a vector:

```r
library(tidyverse)

T8 <- tibble(id = letters[1:10],
             start = sample(1000000:9999999, 10))


values <- T8 |> pull(start)

get_pos1 <- function(x) {
  T8 %>%
    mutate(abs_diff = abs(start - x)) %>% 
    arrange(abs_diff) %>% 
    slice_head(n = 1)
}

map_df(values, get_pos1)
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>    id      start abs_diff
#>    <chr>   <int>    <int>
#>  1 a     8122151        0
#>  2 b     5460739        0
#>  3 c     2863191        0
#>  4 d     1997677        0
#>  5 e     2303171        0
#>  6 f     6267346        0
#>  7 g     1511788        0
#>  8 h     2189209        0
#>  9 i     6638907        0
#> 10 j     8081678        0
```

Albeit, it's still unclear what you're trying to achieve and we can't try this on your actual data with no data sample. Feel free to edit question if further info is needed.